# determine order of operations in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo
WHERE Name IN ('name1', 'name2') 
  AND (Date<'2013-01-01' AND Date>'2010-01-01') 
  AND Type = 1
```

Is there a way to force the SQL server to evaluate the expressions in the order I determine and not what the query optimizer says? For example I want the `IN` clause evaluated first, the output of that evaluated by `Type = 1` and finally the dates, in EXACTLY that order.

Comment: You can use subqueries to filter out the rows you want to be filtered 1st and then do you other operations.

Comment: Why does it matter in what order the predicates are evaluated?

Comment: true AND true AND true always evaluates to true. Why do you think forcing SQL Server to evaluate truth in a particular order will gain you anything?

Comment: The optimizer is clever. You can't fool him into doing something silly.

Comment: Attempting to outsmart the optimizer usually isn't a good idea.

Comment: Besides why (which is crucial), you also have to clarify if you want this exact order of evaluations to happen independently per row of the table or strictly for all of them (first evaluate the `Name IN ('name1', 'name2')` for all rows, then the `Type = 1` for all rows and then the `date ...` for all rows.)

Comment: SQL is a *declarative* language, meaning you are only supposed to declare *what* you want. This aspect of the language implies that it should be the optimiser's job to figure out *how* to go about bringing the results you want in the best possible way.

Comment: You could have 3 queries with Intersect to force an order but I don't see the point.  Why so do you feel you need to force and order?  (A and B) = (B and A)

Comment: @M.Ali - That doesn't guarantee anything. See [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). The optimizer inlines them and still can rearrange the predicates.

Comment: If your problem is efficiency, this is not the way to ask a question. Try by adding the table definition, all the indexes and the actual execution plan of the slow query. SQL-Server's optimizer is nothing but retarded.

Comment: Then this question is not about the order of evaluation of a where clause but about what index you need to best support the query you have.

Comment: @user1151923 - Was this hash join hint when using table variables? The optimiser generally assumes a single row emitted for these so you can end up with inappropriate nested loops. If you ask a new question with the info requested by ypercube we can take a look at what the actual issue is here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is largely possible (though there are some caveats and counter examples [discussed in the answers here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12941/3690))

```
SELECT *
FROM   Foo
WHERE  1 = CASE
             WHEN Name IN ( 'name1', 'name2' ) THEN
               CASE
                 WHEN Type = 1 THEN
                   CASE
                     WHEN ( Date < '2013-01-01'
                            AND Date > '2010-01-01' ) THEN 1
                   END
               END
           END
```

But why bother? There are only very limited circumstances in which I can see this would be useful (e.g. preventing divide by zero if an earlier predicate evaluated to `0`).

Wrapping the predicates up like this makes the query completely unsargable and prevents index usage for any of the three (otherwise sargable) predicates. It guarantees a full scan reading all rows.

To see an example of this

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
  (
     Id     INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     Name   VARCHAR(10),
     [Date] DATE,
     [Type] TINYINT,
     Filler CHAR(8000) NULL
  )

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Name
  ON Foo(Name)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Date
  ON Foo(Date)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Type
  ON Foo(Type)

INSERT INTO Foo
            (Name,
             [Date],
             [Type])
SELECT TOP (100000) 'name' + CAST(0 + CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) AS VARCHAR),
                    DATEADD(DAY, 7 * CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1), '2012-01-01'),
                    0 + CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1)
FROM   master..spt_values v1,
       master..spt_values v2
```

Then running the original query in the question vs this query gives plans

[image]

Note the second query is costed as being 100% of the cost of the batch.

The Query optimizer left to its own devices first seeks into the 414 rows matching the `type` predicate and uses that as a build input for the hash table. It then seeks into the 728 rows matching the `name`, sees if it matches anything in the hash table and for the 4 that do it performs a key lookup for the other columns and evaluates the `Date` predicate against those. Finally it returns the single matching row.

The second query just ploughs through all the rows in the table and evaluates the predicates in the desired order. The difference in number of pages read is pretty significant.

#### Original Query

```
Table 'Foo'. Scan count 3, logical reads 23,
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0
```

#### Nested case

```
Table 'Foo'. Scan count 1, logical reads 100373
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. This ensures (as you say with some caveats) the order of execution for every row. We could also use temporary tables, to enforce this at a table level (first check the `IN` condition, save at temp1, then check ... save at temp2, ...)

Comment: @ypercube - Also it isn't really clear what "order of evaluation" means in all cases anyway. e.g. in the first plan it evaluates rows  with the matching `type` first then evaluates those matching `name`. So in one sense it evaluates that first. But it returns all matching `name`rows from the seek not just those that have already been proven to match the `type`.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer, but I solved my specific case by moving my predicates to join conditions instead and then I was able to force the order by using join hints. Query runtime went from 2 min to 2 sec.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: NO!

You can try to use brackets, hints, study query plan, etc.

But is that wise to mess up with engine/optimizer that way?
You ill need a lot of study and experience to outsmart the optimizer, that said, please let the engine take care of that details for you.

Comment: @Blam - `Intersect` doesn't guarantee anything with respect to this.

Comment: @MartinSmith Agree.  I had only seen Intersect in the order of the query but I played with it and got some query plans not the order of the query.

Comment: As I said you can TRY. Even to change query plan is tricky and requires some knowledge at how engine parses and executes. Also you need to know about hints, etc. Martin posted a way it "works".